# Flatten a 3rd Party XML feed?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to take an XML feed from a 3rd party source and flatten it.

The current XML feed resembles this:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <idnumber></idnumber>
        <location>
            <region></region>
            <street-address></street-address>
            <city-name></city-name>
            <state-code></state-code>
            <zipcode></zipcode>
            <latitude></latitude>
            <longitude></longitude>
        </location>
        <details>
            <name></name>
            <status></status>
            <price></price>
            <bedrooms></num-bedrooms>
            <bathrooms></bathrooms>
            <lot-size></lot-size>
            <square-feet></square-feet>
            <property-type></property-type>
            <attributes></attributes>
            <description></description>
        </details>
        <pictures>
            <picture>
                <picture-url></picture-url>
            </picture>
    </property>
</properties>
```

However, I really need to flatten the XML to this:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <idnumber></idnumber>
        <region></region>
        <street-address></street-address>
        <city-name></city-name>
        <state-code></state-code>
        <zipcode></zipcode>
        <latitude></latitude>
        <longitude></longitude>
        <name></name>
        <status></status>
        <price></price>
        <bedrooms></num-bedrooms>
        <bathrooms></bathrooms>
        <lot-size></lot-size>
        <square-feet></square-feet>
        <property-type></property-type>
        <attributes></attributes>
        <description></description>
        <picture>
                <picture-url></picture-url>
        </picture>
    </property>
</properties>
```

I've been reading up on the XLST stylesheets to attempt this, however am I just wasting my time since the original feed is hosted on a 3rd party in which I can't edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want.  The identity template copies everything to the output, while the other three templates cause the second-level tags to be omitted while still copying their content.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property/location">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property/details">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property/pictures">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[*]">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <idnumber></idnumber>
        <location>
            <region></region>
            <street-address></street-address>
            <city-name></city-name>
            <state-code></state-code>
            <zipcode></zipcode>
            <latitude></latitude>
            <longitude></longitude>
        </location>
        <details>
            <name></name>
            <status></status>
            <price></price>
            <bedrooms></bedrooms>
            <bathrooms></bathrooms>
            <lot-size></lot-size>
            <square-feet></square-feet>
            <property-type></property-type>
            <attributes></attributes>
            <description></description>
        </details>
        <pictures>
            <picture>
                <picture-url></picture-url>
            </picture>
        </pictures>
    </property>
</properties>
```

**produces the wanted, correct output**:

```
<properties>
   <property>
      <idnumber/>
      <region/>
      <street-address/>
      <city-name/>
      <state-code/>
      <zipcode/>
      <latitude/>
      <longitude/>
      <name/>
      <status/>
      <price/>
      <bedrooms/>
      <bathrooms/>
      <lot-size/>
      <square-feet/>
      <property-type/>
      <attributes/>
      <description/>
      <picture>
         <picture-url/>
      </picture>
   </property>
</properties>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use and overriding **[the identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Good observation, fixed. :)